# How Do I Access MySQL Server on My Website?

Tags: python, mysql

I created a website that needs to access a MySQL server on my PC at home but I can't to connect it

I get this error

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my public ip' (10061)
```

Do I use my PC's public IP? or does the server have its own?

I Already Set The bind-address to `0.0.0.0` and opened the port 3306 I can connect to the server using localhost and my private IP

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` which is the default value of localhost to connect if both the website and the MySQL are on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

**for local database access (your own internal network)**

1. use localhost or 127.0.0.1

**for external database access:**

1. go to your router's (device) administrative dashboard via [10.0.0.1](http://10.0.0.1/) or [192.168.0.1](http://192.168.0.1/)
2. enable port forwarding for **port 3306** and point it to your machine.
3. allow inbound access to port 3306 for mysql in your computers firewall settings
4. use whatsmyip.org (from your pc)
5. set that ip address on your website.